# Swing Methods on submission of button

Tags: java, swing, frame, jbutton

How to close current frame (Frame1) and open a new frame (Frame2) already created and pass the data to frame2 from frame1 on the clicking of button?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question little more . What is the scenario ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)<sup>1</sup>.  Either that or one `JFrame` and one or more `JDialog`<sup>2</sup> instances.

1. [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
2. [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 2):

The very best way to accomplish this, is very much told to you by @Andrew Thompson.
And the other way to accomplish, the motive of the question as described in the code. Here as you make object of your new `JFrame`, you have to pass the things you need in the other class as an argument to the other class, or you can simply pass the object(with this you be passing everything in one go to the other class)

A sample code for a bit of help :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoFramesExample
{
    public JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private SecondFrame secondFrame;

    public TwoFramesExample()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        tfield = new JTextField(10);
        tfield.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tfield.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        button = new JButton("NEXT");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                // Here we are passing the contents of the JTextField to another class
                // so that it can be shown on the label of the other JFrame.
                secondFrame = new SecondFrame(tfield.getText());                
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(tfield, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new TwoFramesExample();
            }
        });
    }
}

class SecondFrame
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private TwoFramesExample firstFrame;

    public SecondFrame(String text)
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        label = new JLabel(text);
        button = new JButton("BACK");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                firstFrame = new TwoFramesExample();
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this be of some help.

Regards

Comment: +1.  `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` see also [`setLocationByPlatform(true)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556).  Perfect for situations like this.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Thankyou, exactly that's what I was looking for, since I just found out from one of your answers somewhere about this thingy :-)  Regards